# How should I write Jest Test cases for styled component and spy on `:after` to verify if the styles apply correctly via props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-test-renderer

I have developed the below component

```
// Button.js
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Button = styled.button`
    position: relative;

    &::after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: ${props => props.width}px; /* Use the received width prop */
        /* other pseudo-element styles */
    }
;

export default Button;
```

I need to test the width changes correctly